# Обход DOM дерева и изменение его элементов

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть массив со значениями, необходимо обойти dom дерево и заполнить содержимое элементов c классом child-elem элементами из массива. Получается что ко всем ссылкам добавляется последний элемент массива. Подскажите что делаю не так.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
</div>
<div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
</div>
<div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
</div>
```

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
let div = '.child-elem',
elems = document.querySelectorAll(div),
elem,
key;

for (key in elems) {
  elem = elems[key];
  for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    elem.innerHTML = arr[i]
   }
}
```

Comment: Ну так вы во вложенном цикле for сперва записываете в ссылку 1, потом стираете старое значение и записываете 2, потом опять стираете и туда же записываете 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообще это решается одним циклом. но есть вопросы по поводу а что делать если элементов дом больше чем элементов в массиве? или наоборот а так это 
делается примерно так

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
let div = '.child-elem',
elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(div)),
elem,
key;


for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  elems[i].textContent = arr[i]
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
</div>
<div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
</div>
<div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
</div>
```

в твоем же случае  внутренний цикл последовательно записывает все значения массива в один и тот же элемент и потом переходит на следующий. 
так и получается что всегда последнее значение во всех элементах.

Comment: Спасибо что помогли разобраться!

Answer (score 1):

> Получается что ко всем ссылкам добавляется последний элемент массива.

Вы перезаписываете значения.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let div = '.child-elem',
  elems = document.querySelectorAll(div),
  key;
i = 0

for (key in elems) {
  // Добавит цифкру в child-elem
  elems[key].innerHTML = arr[i++] || 'empty' // при разной длине массивов будет печатать empty
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="parent-elem">
    <a class="child-elem"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```